# Django AllAuth, why does Facebook signup ask for password from an already logged in user?

Tags: python, django, facebook-graph-api, django-allauth

So I'm using Django allAuth to allow Facebook signup on my webapp.
However, I find it weird that when a user is already logged-in to their Facebook account and tries to sign-up/log-in to use the webapp, their Facebook password is requested again.

**Update:** this comes from the configuration  `'AUTH_PARAMS': {'auth_type': 'reauthenticate'}` in the `SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS` setting. Changing to `{'auth_type': 'https'}` removes the second check but also removes any other prompt. It just signs in/up rights away. I think that's a bit too little feedback to the user.

If I go on AirBnB or Buzzfeed and do exactly the same thing, I get prompted "Do you want to continue as Jad?". No second password entry. How can I give this kind of feedback to users that click my facebook sign in/up button?

Comment: I believe it may be due to `ACCOUNT_SESSION_REMEMBER (=None)` [configuration](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html). You can change it to *True*, but my guess is that it's not recommended.